# Найти, вставить, перезаписать в файл

Tags: c#

Что-то до меня не доходит как надо правильнее. Есть строки в `.txt`, и надо вставить палку в начале этих строк, длинна которых <= 3, и перезаписать только их, все остальное не должно быть затронуто..Да, вопрос конечно туповатый, но я чет не понимаю, как решить....

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test1.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < file1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (file1[i].Length <= 3)
            {
                string newlines = file1[i].Insert(0, "|");
                Console.WriteLine(newlines);
                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\test1.txt", file1[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines` перезаписывает каждый раз файл, а не дописывает в конец. Плюс вы теряете все строки длиной больше 3. Советую вместо `foreach` пройтись с помощью `for(int i = 0;i<file1.Length;i++)` и просто перезаписывать нужный элемент массива. И уже в конце записать весь массив в файл с помощью той же `File.WriteAllLines`.

Comment: @John Изменил вопрос

Comment: Я же сказал, что WriteAllLines каждый раз перезаписывает файл и записывает указанные строки. Почитайте описание метода. Короче уберите из условия if этот метод и вставьте его после for в виде: File.WriteAllLines("путь", file1)